# Screen Tearing when rendering using Windows API

Tags: winapi, framebuffer

I am trying to render an animation using Windows API. My problem is that half of the screen shows the previous frame, and the bottom half shows the current frame. I thought that this would be fixed when using a double buffer, but I have inserted

```
BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, iWidth, iHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

which I understand is a double buffer, but the horizontal division still exists. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BitBlt` is not synchronized to the vertical blank, so if you `BitBlt` to the screen at the same time the hardware is rendering to the display, it may tear. Double-buffering with `BitBlt` reduces the likelihood of tearing but does not eliminate it. To eliminate it, you need to do your `BitBlt` during the vertical blank period.

Comment: As Adrian noted below, various Direct interfaces give you access to the vertical blank. GDI rendering does not.

Answer (score 2):

GDI BitBlt wasn't designed for rapid, continuous animation.  Whether you get tearing or not may depend on your hardware and drivers.

There are other graphics APIs, like Direct2D and Direct3D (and the deprecated DirectDraw) which will let you synchronize to the vertical sync.